# How to split data to train and test ? Cross validation possible ? M-estimation or OLS?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have 26 observations to apply a simple linear regression but when I split the data to 70% for train and 30% for test data usually the results for the test data (R squared / P value) are not good. Is it because the samples for the test are too small ? 8 or 9 observation are not enough ? What should I do ? no random state so he the algorithm choose the data randomly
Also wondering how to choose between OLS and M-estimation(which is more resistant to outliers which I have on my data check below because Variable B is impacted by other variables except A) to apply for my dataset.
this is the code I have done so far and looking to do cross validation in the train data.
Is it possible according to the number of observations I have?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\AchourAh\\Desktop\\PL32_PMM_03_09_2018_SP_Level.xlsx",'Sheet1') 
data1 = data.fillna(0) #Replace null values of the whole dataset with 0
print(data1)
X = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),1].values.reshape(-1, 1) 
Y = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),2].values.reshape(-1, 1)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size =0.33)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('SP00114585')
plt.xlabel('COP COR Quantity')
plt.ylabel('PAUS Quantity')
plt.show()
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('SP00114585')
plt.xlabel('COP COR Quantity')
plt.ylabel('PAUS Quantity')
plt.show()
X2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
est = sm.OLS(Y_train, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
X3 = sm.add_constant(X_test)
est3 = sm.OLS(Y_test, X3)
est4 = est3.fit()
print(est4.summary())
```

This is an example of the data I have and my goal is not to predict a good model but to describe the impact of variable A on B. Also when analyzing the whole data together results are always better than splitting the data

```
   Variable A   Variable B
      87.000    573.000
      90.000    99.000
     258.000    339.000
     180.000    618.000
           0    69.000
      90.000    621.000
      90.000    231.000
     210.000    345.000
     255.000    255.000
       0              0
     213.000    372.000
     405.000    405.000
     162.000    162.000
     405.000    405.000
           0    186.000
     105.000    252.000
     474.000    501.000
     531.000    531.000
     549.000    549.000
     525.000    525.000
     360.000    660.000
     546.000    546.000
     645.000    645.000
     561.000    600.000
     978.000    1.104.000
     960.000    960.000
```

Also, plotted the results using SKlearn and analyzing the results based on the statsmodels. Can I assume that the plotted results are represented by the values due to statsmodels or there is something to change in the code ?

Comment: generally speaking - 26 observations is really not much referring to the range your numbers can have..

Comment: values are explained in terms of Quantity. but how you assumed that 26 observations is not much for a simple linear regression ?

Comment: because your values vary between 0 and 1104, that's why I think you need more data for a good approximation..

Comment: and what do you think about OLS or M-estimation for describing the impact of Aon B and the problem of outliers caused by Variable B which is impacted by other variables that Variable A ? Cross Validation useful in my case or is it going to ruin the model ? what about random state should I leave it like that don't mention it ?

Comment: Visual inspection of a scatterplot of the posted data indicates two different groups of data to my eyes. Might there be a reason to separate what looks like two data groups into two different regressions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule

Answer (score -1):

```
Y=df["Column name"]

X=df[[ "All other Columns"]]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 465)
```

Good luck